# Store about and contacts in database

Tags: database, database-design, structure

I want to know if it would make sense to store the website *about text* and *contacts* in a database instead of just writing it in the html, and how would I do that?

I've been thinking just one table for each with the information and no id (since I only want to store one version of everything), but that doesn't make a lot of sense, I think.

The about table should contain the text and the contacts should contain an address, coordinates, email and phone number.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question *might* get flagged as off topic, but I have some thoughts.  I would only put stuff in a database that would be updated frequently.  Simply putting text in a DB that never really changes doesn't get you any benefit and just adds complexity and burden on your DB.  If you find yourself copying the same web text to different pages of your site, make it text you include.

User information like logins,etc. that is added/updated/deleted should clearly live in a DB.  But unless your `About Us` kind of data is going to be changed constantly or you make a tool that allows somebody else to update it, don't put that in the DB.

Comment: Thank you! *By the way, why is it off topic? So I can change it. I'm new, so I'm still learning how things work around here.*

Comment: @cantthinkofone Sometimes if a question is about an opinion and not an actually syntax type question with actual code problems people will flag it as off topic.  I think your question is perfectly fine though as it really is about code.  And welcome to StackOverflow!